# Finitely presented modules admitting projective covers

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, projective-modules

A ring $R$ is called semi-perfect if every finitely generated $R$-module has a projective cover, and it can be proved that this is equivalent to say that the category consisting of the finitely generated projective $R$-modules is Krull-Schmidt. I was wondering, and what about the rings $R$ such that every finitely presented $R$-module has a projective cover? Do these rings have a special name, and are there characterizations of these rings, just like there are for semi-perfect rings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such rings were called "$F$-semiperfect", and more recently (thanks to rschweib for the information) "semiregular".

One characterization is that these are the rings $R$ such that $\bar{R}=R/J(R)$, the quotient by the Jacobson radical, is von Neumann regular and idempotents lift from $\bar{R}$ to $R$. This is analogous to the characterization of semiperfect rings as those for which $\bar{R}$ is semisimple and idempotents lift from $\bar{R}$ to $R$.

Some old references:

*Oberst, Ulrich; Schneider, Hans-Jürgen*, [**Die Struktur von projektiven Moduln. (The structure of projective modules.)**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01406080), Invent. Math. 13, 295-304 (1971). [ZBL0232.16020](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0232.16020).

*Azumaya, Goro*, [**F-semi-perfect modules**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(91)90065-G), J. Algebra 136, No. 1, 73-85 (1991). [ZBL0717.16005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0717.16005).

Comment: I think one will find through a google search that the more common name for what you are calling an "F-semiperfect ring" nowadays is "semiregular ring."

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks, I didn't know that! The only reason I knew where to look at all was that I had some reason (that I've now forgotten) to look at Azumaya's paper many years ago.

Comment: https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/ADBAFC94AF50955CF3EC098BE5A1F582/S0008414X00020678a.pdf/semiregular_modules_and_rings.pdf seems a good reference

Comment: Semiregular rings show up quite a bit in the study of exchange rings.